# Laravel Sanctum SPA - how to make sure user is only logged in on one device?

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

I'm currently using Santum SPA autentication and noticed that I can login from mozilla and chrome at the same time. This means that users can login from different devices. How do I prevent this with Sanctum SPA Authencation?

The thing is I think I should be able to do this if I use Sanctum Tokens since I can easily check if the user has an existing token.

```
$tokens = $user->tokens;
```

However, the documentation says:

> You should not use API tokens to authenticate your own first-party SPA. Instead, use Sanctum's built-in SPA authentication features.

The things I'll lose if I use sanctum tokens for SPA:

> This approach to authentication provides the benefits of CSRF
> protection, session authentication, as well as protects against
> leakage of the authentication credentials via XSS.

or is this outside the scope of Laravel Sanctum?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After googling I'm convinced that this functionality is not included in Laravel SPA Sanctum out-of-the-box.

But I found this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwq5YrNND0k&t=708s) that made this possile.

Answer (score 1):

You Can delete User's other Tokens whenever he logs in from a new device using a new token.

```
$user->tokens()->where('id', '!=' ,$user->currentAccessToken()->id)->delete();
```

Comment: You're talking about Sanctum's Token Authentication. Like I said in my post, I can do that if I'm using tokens. Here I'm talking about Sanctum's SPA Authentication (no tokens), which is used for first-party SPA.